# iPhone 6 and 6 plus giving wrong frame, bounds values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, iphone-6

I have my app build on Xcode 5.1.1 but once upgraded on Xcode 6 facing the problem with frame size as per new sizes iPhone 6 has 750x1334 resolution but, getting output 480x300 does anyone has faced the same problem with iOS 8, iPhone 6 or even on iPhone 6 plus simulators

just run the app and NSLog the following lines

```
NSLog(@"Width - %f, Height - %f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"Width - %f, Height - %f",self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

output:

Width - 480.000000, Height - 300.000000
 Width - 480.000000, Height - 300.000000

I know from iOS 8 bound.size is orientation dependent but my question is why it giving me 480x300 in place of actual 667x355

Comment: Did you add the correct Launch screen to the asset catalog?

Comment: @rckoenes adding the launch screen makes the app run in compatible mode means leaving black band at top & bottom.

Comment: Did you add specific launch images for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus? They are called "Retina HD 5.5" and "Retina HD 4.7"

Comment: Add launch images of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Comment: @Vijayyadav thanks bro but launch images has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You Click on `MainWindow.Xib` and Select The Window

Right Head side Show the Attribute inspector  in   checkmark on FullScreen At Launch And Visible At Launch and i write Down setup on Image Follow us

[image]