# iPhone 6 resizing issue

Tags: swift, ios8-extension

I am creating a custom keyboard, and it looks great on the iphone 5 and 5S, but when it shows up on the iphone 6 and 6plus (in the simulator) it cuts off at the iphone 5 size. I assume this is because the size of my .xib file is 320x240, but I remember them saying iPhone 6 is supposed to resize automatically? If this is the case, what is the width of the iPhone 6 screen? Do I need to make separate .xib files for each screen size? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you don't have to add different nib files I faced the problem with getting wrong frames on iPhone 6 and 6 plus simulator you can get correct frames by adding launch images for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus? They are called "Retina HD 5.5" and "Retina HD 4.7" or check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232686/iphone-6-and-6-plus-giving-wrong-frame-bounds-values)

Comment: I added launch images, but the same thing occurs. My problem is that it's not scaling at all, and I can't think of anything other than making separate nib files

Comment: If you are getting the wright frames I will suggest you to use Auto-layouts in place of creating new nib for custom keyboard

Comment: How would I use auto-layout to determine what size to make the subview for the keyboard? What if I want them to look slightly different?

Comment: That's what I asked if you are getting the wright frames, auto-layouts will resize the custom keyboard to the width and height as per the devices, but if you want them to look different than you should go ahead with 2 diff nibs

Comment: I wasn't sure what wright frames were... Thanks for the help! :)