# Xcode 6.2 does't recognise iphone 6 in [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667)?TRUE:FALSE

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I can't identify My iPhone 6 size in Xcode 6.2.
In first image I run in iPhone 6 and in command output line
"po self.view.frame" return iphone 5 size.

This problem return only with iphone 6 , I tested it with different iPhones 6 devices

I launch images for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus like they called "Retina HD 5.5" and "Retina HD 4.7 .

[image]

When I run this app in iphone 6 simulator this work fine.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 6 and 6 plus giving wrong frame, bounds values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232686/iphone-6-and-6-plus-giving-wrong-frame-bounds-values)

Comment: Spectravideo328 this post not work for me )-: